# How to open a modal by clicking on the first <td> element of each <tr>(row) in a datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

My requirement is to open a modal by clicking on the first td element of each row and the modal should be filled with corresponding row td data values. At the moment I am able to capture the click on a row to show the modal with corresponding td values. Here is my code:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {      
            $('#table_id').DataTable();    
            var table = $('#table_id').DataTable();
        $('#table_id tbody').on('click','tr', function () {
            $(".modal-body div span").text("");
            $(".name input").val(table.row(this).data()[0]);
            $(".address input").val(table.row(this).data()[1]);
            $(".salary input").val(table.row(this).data()[2]);
            $(".code input").val(table.row(this).data()[3]);  
         }
            $("#modal_name").modal("show");
     });
```

This code is working perfectly to get the required results by clicking anywhere on the entire row. But I want to get the same result by clicking on only the first td element of each row. It would be great if anyone could provide assistance.

Comment: `$('#table_id').on('click', 'td:first-child', f...)`

Comment: This is not working. My td:first-child is inside anchor tag. Is that something which is causing problem here ?

Comment: A `<td>` element may only be inside a `<tr>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td . Moreover, your JavaScript depends strongly on an HTML structure. If you want efficient help, you should post that HTML also

Comment: This is my tbody:

Comment: <tbody> 
<%ArrayList<Notes> wb = (ArrayList<Notes>)request.getAttribute("listNote");
               for(Notes w:wb){%>
        
      <tr>
      <td><%=w.getName()%></td>
      <td><%=w.getCode()%></td>
      <td><%=w.getDate()%></td>
      <td><%=w.getAssignment()%></td>
                        
     </tr>
            <%}%>
</tbody>

Comment: After this, I am using datatable to render the first td as an anchor

Comment: $('#table_id').DataTable( {
     
          columnDefs: [
              { targets: [0, 1, 2], visible: true},
              { targets: '_all', visible: false },
              {  
                  targets: 0,  
                  render: function (data, type, row, meta) {

Comment: if (type === 'display') {  
                          data = '<a href="#" class="text-gx-bold card-link middle-black notename"><b>' + data + '</b></a>';  
                      }  
      
                      return data;  
                  }  
              }  
          ],
          responsive: true,
          "autoWidth": false,
    
     } );

Comment: everything works as expected, the only issue is I want the click event to fire only for first td not for entire row

Comment: In the meantime I've made an answer based on what I guessed from your original post. You should know you can edit your question rather than posting code in comments. Hope it helps.

Comment: Last advise: please don't use scriptlets in your code. Since about a dozen years, usage of those `<%...%>` is deprecated. You should look into **jstl**: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages_Standard_Tag_Library

Comment: I just edited my answer to better fit your structure with an anchor `<a>` rendered inside your `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

Let's make some guesses about what you're trying to do here...
Seems you're using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) and [modal](https://jquerymodal.com/).

Going from this hypothesis, and given what you added in your comments, here's how I'd do it:

```js
$(_e => {
  const table = $('#my-datatable').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
      {
        targets: 0,
        render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
          if (type === 'display')
            return '<a href="#" class="text-gx-bold card-link middle-black notename"><b>' + data + '</b></a>';
          return data;
        },
      }
    ]
  });
  // ...
  table.on('click', 'td:first-child', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const row = table.row(e.target.closest('tr'));
    const rowData = row.data();
    const dialog = $("#my-modal form").clone();
    dialog.find('#data1 input').val(rowData[0]);
    dialog.find('#data2 input').val(rowData[1]);
    dialog.on('submit', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      /* Do your stuff */
      $.modal.close();
    });
    dialog.modal('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.modal-edit footer {
 text-align: right
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <main class="table-container">
      <table id="my-datatable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1-1</td><td>Data 1-2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 2-1</td><td>Data 2-2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 3-1</td><td>Data 3-2</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </main>
    
    <aside id="my-modal" hidden>
      <form class="modal-edit">
        <div class="field" id="data1">
          <label>Data 1:</label> <input type="text" name="data1" />
        </div>
        <div class="field" id="data2">
          <label>Data 2:</label> <input type="text" name="data2" />
        </div>
        <footer>
          <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </footer>
      </form>
    </aside>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

The second argument of `table.on` is a filter for child elements that should trigger the `click` event.

For click event `e`, `e.target` is set to the innermost element that received the click (in your case , the `<b>` inside the `<a>`).

You can use the JavaScript function `closest` to construct a datatables `row` from target's parent `<tr>` element (would also work with `<td>`)

Other needed improvements set apart, your code will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I tried using your code. It is not working. It shows an error:   Uncaught TypeError: 'querySelector' called on an object that does not implement interface Element.

Comment: @Hliquid The code I gave does run: you can run it right here using the snippet. Now you might have trouble adapting it to your exact scenario, but in this case, pointing you to the exact cause will be hard. Error message seems to point to the lines where I'm using the `find` jQuery function to update values inside the modal dialog. Have you selected an existing element to clone and use as dialog ?